# Wordpress Redirects to Parent Pages or Categories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

What I am trying to do is to redirect 404 to the next possible page/category. The following is a detailed description of what I want:

If the user falls on the following:

- `www.domain.com/about/(any text that generates 404)` it should automatically redirect to `www.domain.com/about`
- `www.domain.com/category/(any text that generates 404)` it should automatically redirect to `www.domain.com/category`
- `www/domain.com/about/sub-about/(any text that generates 404)` it should automatically redirect to `www.domain.com/about/sub-about`

I hope that describes what I am looking for. I would love if my fellows here post a solution to this. I have tried using the 404 redirected plugin but it is not auto redirecting. I am open to any solution as long as it works on wordpress.

Comment: I think the edition changed the question!! Those are not the initial target urls and makes no sense to redirect to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a code like this one in the 404 script might work:

```
<?php
$Referrer = wp_get_referer( ) ;
if ( $Referrer = 'http://www.domain.com/' ) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="http://www.domain.com/about/";</script>' ;
}
elseif ( $Referrer = 'http://www.domain.com/about/' ) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="http://www.domain.com/about www.domain.com/category/";</script>' ;
}
elseif ( $Referrer = 'http://www.domain.com/about www.domain.com/category/' ) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="http://www.domain.com/category www/domain.com/about/sub-about/";</script>' ;
}
else {
  echo "404 Message" ;
}
?>
```